# How to tell sublime-text open multiple search views?

Tags: sublimetext3

When I use open a `sublime-text 3` search with a `Find in files` option, I open need to search something else in the middle of investigating the initial search results. The new search causes I loose where I was before in the middle of the initial search.

I would like to keep the previous search results in a different place from the new results. Ideally, I would like to search in a new view window than the previous one. Is it possible in `sublime-text 3`?

Comment: Are you referring to literal `Find All` or the `Find in Files` functionality? Using `Find All` in the search panel will add selections at all of the search matches, which doesn't seem to track with investigating the results (or at least not easily).

Comment: @OdatNurd, I mean find in all files. Thanks for asking. I will edit the question